# PHP ob_flush flush() not working

Tags: php, flush

Before saying anything. I have searched for a solution on this. I'm trying to figure this out for a while now.

I am currently trying to show the progress of a ftp download by echo'ing every time a file get's downloaded.

This is part of my code:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');

// ftp connection stuff goes here

$string_length = 4096;

for ($i=0; $i < $filesLength; $i++) {

    if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, './downloads/'.$files[$i]['local'], $files[$i]['server'], FTP_ASCII)) {
        echo 'File: '.$files[$i]['local'].' saved.<br>';

        // $string = str_repeat('.', $string_length);
        // echo '<div style="display:none;">'.$string . '</div>';

        ob_flush();
        flush();
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }

}
```

Theres 2 commented line there that if I uncomment everything it works.

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php states `flush();
    ob_flush();` and not the other way around.

Comment: doesnt' work. Again. if I add the 2 uncommented lines it works perfectly. But adds a bunch of .... in the DOM.

Comment: Can you try with a different browser or pc?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a proper solution I guess.

I ended up using a 4kb string to trigger the flush.

This works, but not as intended.